# Finding a Thinkmap-like engine

Tags: flash, data-visualization

I try to find a Thinkmap-like engine on flash to visualize structured data. Does anybody know any free engines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is [flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There's a great list here:

http://www.wikiviz.org/wiki/Tools

This type of software seems to generally be called "Information Visualization" or perhaps also "Data Visualization"

From the list, this seems the be the only flash-specific one:

- [Flare visualization toolkit](http://flare.prefuse.org): ActionScript library for creating visualizations that run in Adobe Flash Player. Free, Open-source, BSD License. [Demo](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo).

Answer (score 0):

It's not free but I think you'd be better off with the constellation framework http://asterisq.com/products/constellation/framework/implementations.